# How find this sum $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(3n+1)(3n+2)(3n+3)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

Find this sum

> $$I=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(3n+1)(3n+2)(3n+3)}$$

My try: let

> $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{3n+3}}{(3n+1)(3n+2)(3n+3)},|x|\le 1$$

then we have
$$f^{(3)}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{3n}=\dfrac{1}{1-x^3}$$
then we find the $f(x)$,Following is very ugly(can you someone can post your follow solution,) have other simple methods? Thank you very much.

Comment: Generally speaking, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(n+a)(n+b)(n+c)}=-\frac{\psi^{(0)}(a)\cdot(-b+c)+\psi^{(0)}(b)\cdot(-c+a)+\psi^{(0)}(c)\cdot(-a+b)}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}$$ where $$\psi^{(0)}(t)=H_{t-1}-\gamma\qquad\qquad;\qquad\qquad H_t=\int_0^1\frac{1-x^t}{1-x}dx$$ In this case, $a=\frac13$ , $b=\frac23$ , $c=1$.

Comment: Is this formula has any name? why dont you post this as a solution?

Comment: this problem is from comption,so I think this methods some student don't know,Thank you

Comment: I think the integrations are all very doable.  If I have time, I will detail them and produce the result.

Comment: Oh,@RonGordon Thank you,I have wait you, I fell this integral is very ugly.

Comment: @math110 So I know this question is rather old but after stumbling on it, I have one question...why is it that you can still conclude that the geometric series defined by $f^{(3)}(x)$ converges even though $|x|$ is allowed to be 1 from how you defined the function? Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your try is excellent... Note that $f(0)=f'(0)=f''(0)=0$ hence
$$
f(1)=\int_0^1f'(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^1\int_0^xf''(y)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^1\int_0^x\int_0^yf'''(z)\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx,
$$
that is,
$$
2f(1)=\int_0^1(1-z)^2f'''(z)\,\mathrm dz=\int_0^1\frac{1-z}{1+z+z^2}\,\mathrm dz.
$$
The rest is routine. The change of variable $2z+1=\sqrt3t$ yields
$$
2f(1)=\int_{1/\sqrt3}^\sqrt3\frac{\sqrt3-t}{1+t^2}\,\mathrm dt=\left[\sqrt3\arctan t-\frac12\log(1+t^2)\right]_{1/\sqrt3}^\sqrt3.
$$
Note that $\arctan\sqrt3=\pi/3$ and $\arctan1/\sqrt3=\pi/6$, hence
$$
2f(1)=\sqrt3\cdot\left(\frac\pi3-\frac\pi6\right)-\frac12\log4+\frac12\log\frac43,
$$
that is,
$$
f(1)=\frac14\left[\frac\pi{\sqrt3}-\log3\right]\approx0.1788.
$$
**Second method:** The rational fraction is such that
$$
\frac2{(3n+1)(3n+2)(3n+3)}=\frac1{3n+1}-\frac2{3n+2}+\frac1{3n+3},
$$
hence
$$
2f(x)=x^2g_1(x)-2xg_2(x)+g_3(x),\qquad g_k(x)=\sum_{n\geqslant0}\frac{x^{3n+k}}{3n+k}.
$$
Thus, for each $k$,
$$
g'_k(x)=\sum_{n\geqslant0}x^{3n+k-1}=\frac{x^{k-1}}{1-x^3}.
$$
Since $g'_k(0)=0$ for every $k\geqslant1$, this yields
$$
2f(x)=x^2\int_0^x\frac{1}{1-t^3}\mathrm dt-2x\int_0^x\frac{t}{1-t^3}\mathrm dt+\int_0^x\frac{t^2}{1-t^3}\mathrm dt.
$$
The change of variable $t=xu$ yields
$$
2f(x)=x^3\int_0^1\frac{1}{1-x^3u^3}(1-2u+u^2)\mathrm du,
$$
that is,
$$
2f(x)=x^3\int_0^1\frac{1-u}{1-xu}\frac{1-u}{1+xu+x^2u^2}\mathrm du.
$$
When $x\to1$, one obtains once again
$$
2f(1)=\int_0^x\frac{1-u}{1+u+u^2}\mathrm du.
$$
More generally, for every integer $k\geqslant2$,
$$
\sum_{n\geqslant0}\frac{(k-1)!}{(kn+1)(kn+2)\cdots(kn+k)}=\int_0^1\frac{(1-u)^{k-2}}{1+u+\cdots+u^{k-1}}\,\mathrm du.
$$

Comment: This is nice methods,+1,and I think this sum have other nice methos

Comment: You might want to simplify $$ \frac{(1-u)^{k-2}}{\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}u^i}=\frac{(1-u)^{k-2}}{\frac{1-u^k}{1-u}}= \frac{(1-u)^{k-1}}{1-u^k} $$

Comment: @Tim.Ratigan Thanks for your comment. This does not seem to be a *simplification* but introduces a (false) singularity at $u=1$.

Comment: I considered this, but the integral can be considered to limit at $1-\epsilon$ for $\epsilon>0$ arbitrarily close to $0$, which removes the problem of the undefined point.  In any case, L'hopital indicates that $\lim_{u\to 1} \frac{(1-u)^{k-1}}{1-u^k}=0$

Comment: In the first displayed equation for your **second method**, the denominators on the right hand side should be $3n+1$, etc., not $n+1$, etc.

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes. Thanks.

Comment: The first method is ridiculously elegant :)

Comment: @Prism Well... thanks. :-)

Comment: Mr. @Did, could you please explain the step from $$f(1)=\int_0^1\int_0^x\int_0^yf'''(z)\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$$to$$2f(1)=\int_0^1(1-z)^2f'''(z)\,\mathrm dz$$Thanks. （‐＾▽＾‐）

Comment: @V-Moy Integrate first on $(x,y)$, leading to $$2f(1)=2\int_0^1f'''(z)\int_z^1\int_y^1dxdydz=\int_0^1f'''(z)\int_z^12(1-y)dydz={}\int_0^1 f'''(z)(1-z)^2dz.$$

Comment: I can't imagine it, is this 4D object? How come the limit changes from $\displaystyle\int_0^y$ to $\displaystyle\int_y^1$?

Comment: @V-Moy The 3D domain of integration is defined by $$0\lt z\lt y\lt x\lt 1,$$ which yields the bounds of the iterated integrals, either in the order $zyx$ or in the order $xyz$.

Comment: Aha! I get it now. Thanks! I always have a trouble when involving multivariable calculus. +1 ♥(ˆ⌣ˆԅ)

Answer (score 10):

We all know that sums of the form $\displaystyle{\sum\frac1{(n+a)(n+b)}}$ or $\displaystyle{\sum\frac1{(n+a)(n+b)(n+c)}}$ etc., are [telescopic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) in nature, and solving them is trivial: for *integer* values of *a*, *b*, and *c*, that is ! But what if *a*, *b*, and *c* are *not* integers? What then? Suddenly, things aren't so simple and trivial anymore, and the formerly banal and deceitfully tame-looking problem takes on whole new twist, gaining entirely unexpected dimensions of depth, meaning, and insight. The key, when dealing with such surprising turns of events, is to just take a step back, and try to parse or rephrase the older, well-worn solution in terms which might prove useful or relevant to circumventing the obstacles raised by the newly-encountered situation.

---

For instance, it is by no means difficult to show that $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(n+a)(n+b)}}=\frac{H_a-H_b}{a-b}$ , or that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(n+a)(n+b)(n+c)}=\frac{(a-b)\cdot H_c\ +\ (b-c)\cdot H_a\ +\ (c-a)\cdot H_b}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}$$ for natural values of *a*, *b*, *c*. Indeed, the user [Random Variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/16033/random-variable) has already proved it on this thread, though I  now realize that my initial formula is slightly mistaken, in the sense that either the sum should begin at $0$, with the $\gamma$ present, or at $1$, with the $\gamma$ absent. Now, the whole question becomes how to redefine $H_m$ , so as to be able to *extend* its meaning to *non-natural* arguments. For natural arguments, we have the well-known formula $H_m=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^m\frac1k$ . Now, let us take the simple function $f_k(x)=\displaystyle\frac{x^k}k$ , and notice that $f_k'(x)=x^{k-1}$ . And since we know that $\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^mx^{k-1}=\frac{1-x^m}{1-x}}$ , this finally allows us to conclude that $\displaystyle{H_m=\int_0^1\frac{1-x^m}{1-x}dx}$ , which, unlike the previous formula, can easily be extended to non-natural arguments as well. This has already been done by [Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation) two and a half centuries ago, so it's hardly new territory. Now, in our case, $\{a,b,c\}=\left\{\frac13,\frac23,1\right\}$ , and the value of $H_1$ is $1$, so all that's left to do is to compute $H_\frac13$ and $H_\frac23$ using the above formula, since $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(3n+1)(3n+2)(3n+3)}=\frac16+\frac1{27}\cdot\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\left(n+\frac13\right)\left(n+\frac23\right)(n+1)}$$

---

$$H_\frac13=\int_0^1\frac{1-\sqrt[3]x}{1-x}dx=\int_0^1\frac{1-t}{1-t^3}d\left(t^3\right)=\int_0^1\frac1{1+t+t^2}d\left(t^3\right)=\int_{\sqrt[3]0}^{\sqrt[3]1}\frac{3\,t^2}{1+t+t^2}dt=$$

$$=3\int_0^1\left(1-\frac{1+t}{1+t+t^2}\right)dt=3\,\bigg[\int_0^11\cdot dt-\tfrac12\int_0^1\frac{2+2t}{1+t+t^2}dt\bigg]=$$

$$=3\,\bigg[t|_0^1-\tfrac12\bigg(\int_0^1\frac1{1+t+t^2}dt+\int_0^1\frac{1+2t}{1+t+t^2}dt\bigg)\bigg]=$$

$$=3\,\bigg[1-\tfrac12\int_0^1\frac1{\left(t+\frac12\right)^2+\frac34}dt-\tfrac12\cdot\ln\left(1+t+t^2\right)_0^1\bigg]=$$

$$=3\,\bigg[1-\tfrac12\cdot\frac1{\sqrt3/2}\cdot\arctan\bigg(\frac{t+\frac12}{\sqrt3\big/2}\bigg)_0^1-\frac{\ln3}2\bigg]=3-\frac\pi{2\sqrt3}-\tfrac32\ln3.$$

---

Similarly for $\displaystyle{H_{\frac23}=\tfrac32+\frac\pi{2\sqrt3}-\tfrac32\ln3}$ . Then, by substituting these values back into the original formula above, we finally arrive at the desired result $\displaystyle{I=\frac{\pi\sqrt3-3\ln3}{12}}$ .

Comment: An alternate expression is $~H_m~=-\displaystyle\int_0^1\ln\Big(1-\sqrt[m]x\Big)~dx$.

Answer (score 7):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$\ds{
I_{N} \equiv \sum_{n = 0}^{N}{1 \over \pars{3n + 1}\pars{3n + 2}\pars{3n + 3}}\,,
\qquad I = I_{\infty} =\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> I_{N}&\equiv
> {1 \over 6}\sum_{n = 0}^{N}{1 \over n + 1/3}
> -
> {1 \over 3}\sum_{n = 0}^{N}{1 \over n + 2/3}
> +
> {1 \over 6}\sum_{n = 0}^{N}{1 \over n + 1}
> \\[3mm]&=
> {1 \over 6}\sum_{n = 0}^{N}\pars{{1 \over n + 1/3} - {1 \over n + 2/3}}
> +
> {1 \over 6}\sum_{n = 0}^{N}\pars{{1 \over n + 1} - {1 \over n + 2/3}}
> \\[3mm]&=
> {1 \over 18}\sum_{n = 0}^{N}{1 \over \pars{n + 1/3}\pars{n + 2/3}}
> -
> {1 \over 18}\sum_{n = 0}^{N}{1 \over \pars{n + 1}\pars{n + 2/3}}
> \end{align}
> We'll use the well known identity:
> $\ds{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{n + z_{0}}\pars{n + z_{1}}}
>      ={\Psi\pars{z_{0}} - \Psi\pars{z_{1}} \over z_{0} - z_{1}}}$ where $\Psi\pars{z}$ is the $\it\mbox{digamma function}$

\begin{align}
I & = I_{\infty}
=
{1 \over 18}\,{\Psi\pars{1/3} - \Psi\pars{2/3} \over 1/3 - 2/3}
-
{1 \over 18}\,{\Psi\pars{1} - \Psi\pars{2/3} \over 1 - 2/3}
\\[3mm]&=
{1 \over 6}\,\bracks{\Psi\pars{2 \over 3} - \Psi\pars{1 \over 3}}
-
{1 \over 6}\,\bracks{\Psi\pars{1} - \Psi\pars{2 \over 3}}
=
-\,{1 \over 6}\,\Psi\pars{1} - {1 \over 6}\,\Psi\pars{1 \over 3}
+
{1 \over 3}\,\Psi\pars{2 \over 3}
\end{align}
However,
\begin{align}
\Psi\pars{1} &= -\gamma\quad\mbox{where}\ \gamma\ {\it\mbox{is the Euler-Mascheroni constant}}\ \pars{~\gamma = 0.5772\ldots~}
\\[3mm]
\Psi\pars{1 \over 3}&=-\gamma - {\root{3} \over 6}\,\pi - {3 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{3}
\\[3mm]
\Psi\pars{2 \over 3}&=-\gamma + {\root{3} \over 6}\,\pi - {3 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{3}
\\
I & = I_{\infty} =
-\,{1 \over 6}\pars{-\gamma}
-
{1 \over 6}\bracks{-\gamma - {\root{3} \over 6}\,\pi - {3 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{3}}
+
{1 \over 3}\bracks{-\gamma + {\root{3} \over 6}\,\pi - {3 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{3}}
\\[3mm]&=
{\root{3} \over 12}\,\pi - {1 \over 4}\,\ln\pars{3}
\end{align}

> $$\color{#0000ff}{\large
> \sum_{n = 0}^{N}{1 \over \pars{3n + 1}\pars{3n + 2}\pars{3n + 3}}
> =
> {\root{3} \over 12}\,\pi - {1 \over 4}\,\ln\pars{3}} \approx 0.1788
> $$

Answer (score 3):

OK, so let's start with

$$\frac{d^3}{dx^3} f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x^3}$$

where $f(0)=f'(0)=f''(0)=0$.  Note that we may use partial fractions and a little rearranging to find that

$$\frac{1}{1-x^3} = \frac13 \left [\frac{1}{1-x} + \frac{x+\frac12}{\left (x+\frac12\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}}+\frac{3}{2} \frac{1}{\left (x+\frac12\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}}\right ]$$

Integrating and using $f''(0)=0$ we get that

$$f''(x) = -\frac13 \log{(1-x)} + \frac16 \log{(1+x+x^2)} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \arctan{\frac{2 x+1}{\sqrt{3}}} - \frac{\pi}{6 \sqrt{3}}$$

From here the challenge will be managing the various terms rather than individual integrations, which are easily done through parts.  Note that, for example,

$$\int dx \, \log{(1+x+x^2)} = x \log{(1+x+x^2)} - \int dx \frac{2 x^2+x}{x^2+x+1}$$

You may use partial fractions on the latter integral and determine that

$$\int dx \frac{2 x^2+x}{x^2+x+1} = 2 x - \frac12 \log{(1+x+x^2)} - \sqrt{3} \arctan{\frac{2 x+1}{\sqrt{3}}} +C$$

Using a substitution ($u=(2 x+1)/\sqrt{3}$) and integration by parts, we similarly find that

$$\int dx \, \arctan{\frac{2 x+1}{\sqrt{3}}} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left [\frac{2 x+1}{\sqrt{3}} \arctan{\frac{2 x+1}{\sqrt{3}}}  - \frac12 \log{(1+x+x^2)}\right ] + C$$

Omitting a lot of algebra, I find that, using $f'(0)=0$:

$$f'(x) = \frac13 (1-x) \log{(1-x)} - \frac16 (1-x) \log{(1+x+x^2)} + \frac{1+x}{\sqrt{3}}  \arctan{\frac{2 x+1}{\sqrt{3}}} - \frac{\pi}{6 \sqrt{3}} (1+x)$$

Now we integrate once more.  Again, the challenge is bookkeeping, as all the integrals may be done by parts.  Using $f(0)=0$, I get that

$$f(x) = -\frac16(1-x)^2 \log{(1-x)} + \frac{1}{12} (x^2-2 x-2) \log{(1+x+x^2)} + \frac{(x^2+2 x)}{2 \sqrt{3}} \arctan{\frac{2 x+1}{\sqrt{3}}}  - \frac{\pi}{12 \sqrt{3}} (x^2+2 x)$$

The sum is then

$$f(1) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{12} \pi - \frac14 \log{3} \approx 0.178$$

which checks out with, e.g., [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B1/%28%283%20n%2b1%29%283%20n%2b2%29%283%20n%2b3%29%29,%7Bn,0,Infinity%7D%5D&t=crmtb01).

Answer (score 2):

I undeleted my answer and fixed it up since one of the other answers refers to it.

---

In the comments, Lucian mentioned the generalization $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+a)(n+b)(n+c)} = \frac{(b-c) \, \psi(a)+ (c-a) \, \psi(b)+(a-b) \, \psi(c)}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)} \tag{1}$$ where $\psi(x)$ is the digamma function;  $a,b,c >0$; $a \ne b$; $b \ne c$; and $a \ne c$.

We can prove $(1)$ by using the [series representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Series_formula) $$\psi(x) = - \gamma + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+x} \right) \, , \quad x>0.$$

Starting from the right side of $(1)$, we get

$$ \begin{align} &\frac{(b-c) \, \psi(a)+ (c-a) \, \psi(b)+(a-b) \, \psi(c)}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)} \\   &= \small\left[ (b-c)\left(-\gamma + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+a} \right) \right)+ (c-a)\left(-  \gamma + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+b} \right) \right)   + (a-b) \left( -\gamma +\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+c} \right) \right) \right] /{\left((a-b)(b-c)(c-a) \right)} \\  &= \frac{1}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{c-b}{n+a}+\frac{a-c}{n+b} + \frac{b-a}{n+c} \right) \\ &=\frac{1}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \ \frac{bc^{2}-b^{2}c+a^{2}c-ac^{2}+ab^{2}-a^{2}b}{(n+a)(n+b)(n+c)} \\ &= \frac{1}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a-b)(ac-c^{2}-ab+bc)}{(n+a)(n+b)(n+c)} \\ &=\frac{1}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}{(n+a)(n+b)(n+c)} \\ &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+a)(n+b)(n+c)} \end{align}$$