# Limit of a harmonic subseries minus "its" logarithm

Tags: real-analysis, limits, logarithms, harmonic-numbers

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{3k-1} - \frac{1}{3}\ln(n)$

I think that inserting the other terms and then subtracting them would not help. I need just the ideea. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not very difficult to show that, for natural values of *a*, $\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^n}\frac1{n+a}=H_{n+a}-H_a$ , where

$H_n$ is the $n^{th}$ [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). But in our case, $a=-\frac13$ , so we have to extend the formula

or definition of $H_n$ so as to encompass non-natural arguments as well. Luckily for us, [Euler 

 has already done](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation) it some $250$ years ago: $\displaystyle{H_n=\int_0^1\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}dx}$ . Using this, we can now [compute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Special_values_for_fractional_arguments)

the value of $H_{-\frac13}$ to be $\displaystyle{\frac12\bigg(\frac\pi{\sqrt3}-3\ln3\bigg)}$. Now use the fact that $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}H_n-\ln n}=\gamma$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573119#574321)

for more details on how to handle the integral in question.

Comment: Thank you. So because of that $\pi$ that appears in the final result, this cannot be computed without that integral?

Comment: Since *a* is not a natural number, the sum is not [telescopic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series). You might perhaps want to check out the other answers on that page as well. It can't hurt, and maybe you'll find something more accessible.

Comment: If we considered $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n-1}$, nor would be $-\frac{1}{2}$, but it is possible to evaluate its limit.

Comment: $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{2n-1}-\frac12\ln N\right)=\frac\gamma2+\ln2.$$

Answer (score 0):

If it were $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1k-\ln n$, we'd end up with $\gamma$.
So I'd suggest to investigate 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac 3{3k-1}-\frac1k\right)$$

Comment: Sorry, but I'm unable to continue on this path.