# Fourier Series, Parseval Identity

Tags: fourier-series

I need to prove

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2-\alpha^2}=\frac{1}{2\alpha^2}-\frac{\pi}{2\alpha\tan(\alpha\pi)},$$

with $\alpha$ a non integer complex.

I know that I have to use the Parseval's Indentity relation but I don't know whose function's expansion makes this possible.

Comment: For reasons explained [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573119/how-find-this-sum-sum-limits-n-0-infty-frac13n13n23n3/574321#574321), this is the same as showing that $$\int_0^1\frac{x^a-x^{-a}}{1-x}dx=\pi\cot\pi a-\frac1a$$