# Proving that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+1)(2k+1)(4k+1)}=\frac{\pi}{3}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The following problem(p.668, 7) is from *Integrals and Series* [ *Интегралы и ряды*, А.П. Прудников, Ю.А. Брычков, О.И. Маричев.] states that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+1)(2k+1)(4k+1)}=\frac{\pi}{3}$$

How one can show that?

Comment: Hint: re-write as $\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1 \sum x^k dx-2\int_0^1 \sum x^{2k}dx+\frac{8}{3} \int_0^1 \sum x^{4k}\,dx$. Can you see what to do next?

Comment: See the answers on [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573119/how-find-this-sum-sum-limits-n-0-infty-frac13n13n23n3/574321#574321) related post.

Comment: I'd say the title would be more commonly translated as "Integrals and Series"

Comment: @DonAntonio: You are right! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+1)(2k+1)(4k+1)}&=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k+1/2}+\frac{2}{3}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k+1/4}+\frac{1}{3} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k+1} \\
&=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+1/2}+\frac{2}{3} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k+1/4}-\frac{1}{k+1/2} \\
&=-\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+1/2)}+\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+1/4)(k+1/2)} \\
\text{Using Gauss's Digamma Theorem, }\\
&=-\frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{\psi(1)-\psi(1/2)}{1/3-1/2}+ \frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{\psi(1/4)-\psi(1/2)}{1/4-1/2} \\
&=-\frac{1}{6}\cdot \log 16+\frac{1}{6}\cdot 2(\pi+\log4)=\frac{\pi}{3} 
\end{align}