# How to calculate the following sum:

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How may one calculate 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \ \left(\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{3k-1}\right) - \frac{\ln n}{3}\right) \ ?$$

Comment: Manipulations based on the definition of the Euler Mascheroni constant, which is similar, $H_n - log(n)$, might help.

Comment: You may use computational methods to find a sufficient limit for large n, however, I am still thinking of an exact value

Comment: Generally speaking, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\ln n-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k-a}\right)=\pi\cdot\cot(a\pi)+H_a-\gamma,$$ where $H_a=\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{1-x^a}{1-x\ }dx$ is the generalized [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), and $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Mascheroni_constant). In our case, $a=\dfrac13$

Comment: @Lucian Could you please give a link to the statement?

Comment: I don't understand how this question is off-topic (there are currently 3 close votes for that reason).

Comment: I agree. There seems to be a cabal of close-for-no-reason people.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\ln n}3-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{3k-1}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\ln n}3-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{3k+2}\right)=\frac13\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\ln n-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{k+\frac23}\right)$$

Now, suppose that instead of $\dfrac23$ we have a natural number *m*. [Knowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Mascheroni_constant) that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg[\ln n-$

$-\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\bigg]=\gamma,~$ it is trivial to show that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\ln n\!-\!\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k+m}\right]=\gamma+H_m,~$ where $H_m=$

$=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^m\frac1k~$ is the $m^{th}$ [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). The only trouble is that $\dfrac23\not\in\mathbb{N}$, so the above definition

does not apply here in this particular case. Therefore, we must seek to find another one, whose

meaning can easily be extended to non-natural arguments as well. Luckily for us, [Euler already 

 found it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation) three centuries ago! Here it is: $H_a=\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{1-x^a}{1-x~~}dx.~$ In our case, $a=\dfrac23.~$ I have

evaluated a similar one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573119#574321), for $a'=\dfrac13.~$ *Wikipedia* also lists their [values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Special_values_for_fractional_arguments).