# Limit of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac12\ln n $

Tags: limits, summation

It is very well known that:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}-\ln n = \gamma$$
Is there anything known about 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k}-\frac{\ln n}2 $$
or 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{\ln n}2 $$

Edit : Originally the question was :
$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k-1}-\ln n $ which of course is not interesting at all.

Comment: Both the sums will be approximately $0.5 \ln n$, and so when you subtract $\ln n$ and take the limit,  you get something that diverges to $-\infty$.

Comment: @Aaron : good point, revising the question to reflect a deeper question.

Comment: For the revised problems, the first one you can simply factor out $1/2$ to get $\gamma/2$.  I'm not sure off the top of my head how to tackle the second one, though.

Comment: @Aaron : again, 100% correct, I should have seen that. But I leave it as it is. I have seen a relationship between sum of odd inverse squares and sum of even inverse squares.

Comment: Fair point.  With that insight, I think I have a solution.

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615695) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We wish to evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k-1} - \frac{\ln n}{2}$.  Let us take a a given that the limit exists.  Since 
$$\gamma=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{2k} -\ln 2n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2k} +\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2k-1} -\ln n - \ln 2,$$

we can subtract off the sum of even terms to get $\gamma/2 + \ln 2$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}1/(2k), B_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}1/(2k-1).$ Then $A_n + B_n -\ln (2n) \to \gamma.$ This gives

$$A_n + B_n - (\ln 2 +\ln n) \to \gamma,$$ hence $$[A_n - (\ln n)/2] + [B_n - (\ln n)/2  -\ln 2] \to \gamma.$$

We know that $[A_n - (\ln n)/2] \to \gamma/2,$ so it follows that $[B_n - (\ln n)/2  -\ln 2] \to \gamma/2.$ Thus $$B_n - (\ln n)/2  \to \gamma/2 + \ln 2.$$