# Closed expression for infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

How can I find the value of the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(b+n)(a+n)}$$
where $a,b\in[0,1)$?

It is obvious by standard arguments that the series converges, but how can I derive the explicit value dependent on $a$ and $b$.

Thanks

EDIT: $a,b$ can be assumed to be different.

Comment: For fractional *a* and *b*, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573119).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole key is **generalization!** :-) Let us *first* notice that for *natural* values of *a* and *b*, we

have $~\dfrac1{(a+n)(b+n)}=\dfrac1{b-a}\bigg(\dfrac1{a+n}-\dfrac1{b+n}\bigg),~$ turning our sum into a [telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series),

whose value becomes $~\dfrac{H_a-H_b}{a-b}~,~$ where $~H_n=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k~$ for $n\in$ **N**. But what if $n\not\in$ **N** ? :-$)$

Let us notice that $~\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x~~}~,~$ which, by integrating both sides between $x=0$ and

$x=1$, yields $~H_n=\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{1-x^n}{1-x~~}dx,~$ which expression, unlike the abovementioned formula

for [harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), can easily be evaluated for non-natural arguments as well, and, more

than that, when *a* and *b* are fractional rationals, possesses a closed form; e.g., for $n=\dfrac pq~,~$

we simply substitute $t=\sqrt[q]x,~$ and then employ [partial fraction decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) and/or other

available tools which can be used for determining the primitives of [rational functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function). This

approach has been discovered by [Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation) some two and a half centuries ago. A list of exact

values for $H_n$ evaluated at fractional arguments can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Special_values_for_fractional_arguments). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Very nice approach!