# sum of infinite series with telescopes

Tags: analysis

I need help finding the sum of the infinite series
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$$
I have used the partial fraction decomposition to get this as the sum of 
$$\frac{-1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{2(k+2)}+\frac{1}{2k}$$
but don't know where to go from here.
Thanks!

Comment: $$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}\right) - \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{1}{k+2}\right)$$

Comment: But what if the sum [doesn't](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573119) telescope ? :-$)$

Comment: @Lucian Partial fraction decomposition and digamma function always works :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Easier is to use
$$
\frac1{n(n+1)}-\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac2{n(n+1)(n+2)}
$$
and just add. Note that this is a [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Comment: That was the one I was going to give ...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** First observe that $$
\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)
$$ and conclude by telescoping terms.
You end up with
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{N+1}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{N+2}\right)
$$ and then let tend $N$ to $+\infty$.