# Determine sum of the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, closed-form

I have the following problem,

> $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$$

And I try to work as follows:

Hint: Partial Fraction decomposition:

$\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)} &= \frac{a}{n}+\frac{b}{(n+1)}+\frac{c}{(n+2)}\\
&= \frac{a(n+1)(n+2)}{n}+\frac{b(n)(n+2)}{(n+1)}+\frac{c n(n+1)}{(n+2)}\\
&= \frac{(a+b+c)n^2+(a3+2b+c)n+2a}{n(n+1)(n+2)}
\end{aligned}$

$\begin{alignat}{7}
 a &&\; + \;&& b &&\; - \;&& c &&\; = \;&& 0 & \\
3a &&\; + \;&& 2b &&\; + \;&& c &&\; = \;&& 0 & \\
2a &&\; + \;&& 0b &&\; + \;&& 0c&&\; = \;&& 1 &
\end{alignat} $

$$a = \frac{1}{2}; b = -1; c = \frac{1}{2};$$
$$\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)} =\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{(n+2)})-\frac{1}{(n+1)}$$

what follows:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{(n+2)})-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1)}$$

And now, how I can continue?

Note: I found a possible solution in [sum of infinite series with telescopes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989562/sum-of-infinite-series-with-telescopes) but I can not find a clear answer.
Can you help me?
Thanks!

---

**As a summary after the answers:**

We have

$\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)} =\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{(n+2)})-\frac{1}{(n+1)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{(n+1)}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{(n+2)}-\frac{1}{(n+1)}\right)
$

Consequently:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)} =\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{(n+1)}\right)}_{\text{telescoping sums}}+\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{(n+2)}-\frac{1}{(n+1)}\right)}_{\text{telescoping sums}}=
$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\lim\limits_{N \rightarrow \infty}{(1-\frac{1}{N+1})}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\lim\limits_{N \rightarrow \infty}{(\frac{1}{N+2}-\frac{1}{2})} =\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4} = $$

> $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{1}{4}$$

Thank you all for your answers!