# A series that converges to π/3

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, complex-numbers, pi, tessellations

While surfing on YouTube, I stumbled into this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NaL_Cb42WyY) which gave me a new insight about the well-known series 
$$
\frac{\pi}{4} = 1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7}+ \ldots
$$
The idea shown there consists of counting (in a *very* clever way) how many points of the 2d integer lattice lie on a generic circumference of radius $\sqrt{r}, r \in \mathbb{N}$, centered at the origin. Then, we name $N(R)$ the number of points of this kind that lie *inside* the circumference of radius $\sqrt{R}$: as $R$ grows, we can think of $N(R)$ as a fairly good approximation of the area $\pi R$ of the circle, since each of the $N(R)$ points can be thought as the center of a square of area $1$. From the equality $\pi R = N(R)$ we get the series above.

I was fairly amazed by the way this result was obtained, and I started wondering: what if we used the hexagonal lattice (I mean $\mathbb{Z} \times \zeta_3\mathbb{Z}$, where $\zeta_3$ is a non-trivial third root of unity) instead of the integer lattice? Will I get another series to approximate $\pi$?

After some work, following the same kind of argument, I came to this formula:
$$
\frac{\pi}{3} = \sqrt{3} \left (1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{7} - \frac{1}{8} + \ldots \right ) 
$$
or equivalently 
$$
\frac{\pi}{3} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{3}}{9k^2+9k+2}
$$
I have some questions:

- Can anyone give me a proof of this result which does not follow the argument I sketched above? I checked by doing some simple calculations (I also asked Wolfram) and the result seems to hold, but I'd like to be 100% sure...
- The $\frac{\pi}{4}$ formula relates to the expansion of $\arctan(x)$, but I couldn't find any straightforward connection between the $\frac{\pi}{3}$ formula and $\arctan(x)$. I actually couldn't find any connection to the "pi facts" I know or I was able to find. Do anybody know anything that can explain "easily" what's happening here?

Thanks in advance!

---

Comment: Compare [Find the value of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{9n^2+9n+2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632311/find-the-value-of-sum-n-0-infty-frac19n29n2), where the series is computed in various ways (and some are related to $\tan$ or $\arctan$)

Comment: Another one: [Showing $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(3n+1)(3n+2)}=\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112161/showing-sum-n-0-infty-frac13n13n2-frac-pi3-sqrt3).

Comment: Nice! It looks exactly like what I was looking for. I'm so happy that my argument 1) makes sense 2) connects a geometric intuition to some other cool maths. Thanks :)